# Image navigation with text overlay

Tags: image, text, navigation, overlay

I am planing to make a subnavigation for a website I'm working on. The submenu should be 6 pictures, 3 in a row, so it should be a grid with 3 rows and 2 cols.
The whole thing should be responsive of course.
When hovering an image of the navigation, a text should be displayed and centered over the image with a rgba(0,0,0,0.5) background.

I already tried a lot of versions I found of the web, but none of them seems to work. Does anybody have an idea? This is the code so far:

```
<div class="spa_nav">
<a href=""><img src="http://www.sportpresseagentur.at/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/17882.jpg" width="100%"/></a>
<h2>Testtext</h2>
</div>
<div class="spa_nav">
<a href=""><img src="http://www.sportpresseagentur.at/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/17882.jpg" width="100%"/></a>
<h2>Testtext</h2>
</div>
<div class="spa_nav">
<a href=""><img src="http://www.sportpresseagentur.at/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/17882.jpg" width="100%"/></a>
<h2>Testtext</h2>
</div>
<div class="spa_nav">
<a href=""><img src="http://www.sportpresseagentur.at/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/17882.jpg" width="100%"/></a>
<h2>Testtext</h2>
</div>
<div class="spa_nav">
<a href=""><img src="http://www.sportpresseagentur.at/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/17882.jpg" width="100%"/></a>
<h2>Testtext</h2>
</div>
<div class="spa_nav">
<a href=""><img src="http://www.sportpresseagentur.at/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/17882.jpg" width="100%"/></a>
<h2>Testtext</h2>
</div>

.spa_nav{
width:33.33%;
float:left;
}

.spa_nav h2{
text-align:center;
display:none;
}

.spa_nav:hover h2{
display:block;
}
```

How I want it to look: http://www.cssscript.com/demo/image-caption-hover-animations-with-css3-transitions-and-transforms/index.html

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/561td9vx/)  Updated

Comment: recommendations are off-topic here, but if you edit your question with code and an example of one that isn't quite right you can get help fixing the issues

Comment: I don't know how to edit my post but here's a link to what I already have: http://jsfiddle.net/zhrq3135/ - just that the text should be centered within the image and the image should have a color overlay on hover.

Comment: and it should be like this, with 3 images in a row, 2 rows - responsive.
http://www.cssscript.com/demo/image-caption-hover-animations-with-css3-transitions-and-transforms/index.html

Comment: there's an edit button under the question, but I edited to add your code. Can you explain what part isn't working? I don't see the background color either -  is it color for behind the text only?

Comment: There should be the 6 images like you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/zhrq3135/ but when you hover on the images, the text which is now displayed under the images should be on the center of the hovered image with a overlay of rgba(0,0,0,0.5) over the image but behind the text. And the images should be linked to certain pages, as it should behave like a navigation.

Answer (score 0):

The [example you gave](http://www.cssscript.com/image-caption-hover-animations-with-css3-transitions-and-transforms/) included a lot more css than in your jsfiddle which is further down the page, your jsfiddle doesn't even include the rgba(0,0,0,a) overlay you wanted (the example code attaches this to the class called `blur`.

## How the demo works

You are using `<h2>` instead of `<h1>` which the demo uses, but you need do to add extra classes to your HTML, eg

```
<div class="caption">
<div class="blur"></div>
<div class="caption-text">
```

This code belongs immediately above your `<h2>` tag line. It doesn't look like you are using a caption text so that line can be left out but you might want to leave that until the end.

What the CSS should basically do is use `opacity` to show/hide the `<h2>` text, the css ending `:hover` is a pseudoclass, and will run as soon as a hover is done by the user. The css with the `transition` and `ease` statements basically tells it to do a fade-in/fade-out effect if anything else (like `hover` is called).

The easiest way to do things is to start a new piece of code and make it identical to the demo, then change one bit at once and check it works each time. First get the code working with one image, then copy and paste the HTML only 6 times, then change `h1` to `h2` in *both* css and html, and alter `li` to `div` in both and change any class names,  widths or other formatting.

Some important things at the end of the css are `color: #FFF` (white) - which sets the caption color, and `z-index` which makes sure the caption will appear over the top of the images (not behind them!). You can consider using `<li>` instead of `<div>` like the example code does, it will let you remove the bullet points and set the width to 33.3% so that you get 3 per line. It's really common to use `<li>` in this way to make a horizontal menu.

## Responsive code

You are already using width with a percentage, so images will resize automatically. Just make sure you have a `<meta>` tag with the `viewport` statement (google it if that is new to you). You might think about layout changes for tiny screens, eg making it into 6 vertical images for 320px just involves a one-line CSS media query to make each image full width for sizes 320px and smaller: `@media screen only and (max-width:320px) { .span-nav {width: 100$;}}`

Alternatively for very large screens you could use something similar to display 6 images in a horizontal row instead. It all depends on the images: some will look fine 3 to a line on a tiny screen (just over 100px wide), others might look poor when enlarged on a very large screen. There are lots of good blogs about media queries with images.